# Can I use sizeof() or a #define for precision in sprintf of a string?

Tags: c++, c

Lookign at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

for string (%.Ns) precision.

When I use sizeof or a #define length in the precsion it reads it as actual text.

Why is this? What are the rules of this? Does it have to be an integer value only?

i.e. -

```
buffer[50];

sprintf (buffer, "%.sizeof(buffer)s", string);
```

or

```
#define MAX_LEN

sprintf (buffer, "%.MAX_LENs", string);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is it you're trying to print?

Comment: The precision field has to be an integral value.  It can be written as a number right in the format string, or passed as a parameter (see below).  A fractional "number of significant digits to the right of the decimal point" does not have a standard definition, and if you have need for such a beast, you'll need to write your own number-to-string conversion function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything inside quotation marks is part of the string, and the compiler won't even think of touching it.  Instead, you can use a '*' to let `sprintf` know your precision is an extra argument it can read.  Also, you need the '.' before your precision, or otherwise it will be a pad-width instead.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%.*s", (int) sizeof(buffer), string);
```

Comment: So in your example the'*' will be replaced with sizeof(buffer)? (sorry, I did have the "." in there just updated the question, however it still prints as a string.)

Comment: OIC- '*' The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

Comment: @aschepler: Except that `sprintf` will expect an `int` argument for `*` specifier, and you are passing the result of `sizeof`, which is certainly not an `int`. You have to explicitly cat the result of `sizeof` to `int` before passing it to `sprintf`.

Comment: do we want strlen which returns a "size_t" which should be an integer on windows...

Comment: @AndreyT Quite true. I'll fix it. @Tommy No, not strlen(), because it searches for a '\0' to figure out where a string ends, and if the buffer is uninitialized, you have no clue where or whether there is a '\0' in buffer. Besides, it also returns size_t, not int.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way strings work; anything inside the "s will be interpreted as a string. You can use `#define`d numeric constants if you want like this:

```
#define MAX_LEN 50
buffer[50];
sprintf (buffer, "%" #MAX_LEN "s", string);
```

That uses compile-time string concatenation.

Comment: Close, but the stringizing operator is only recognized inside preprocessor directives, like macro definitions.  You'll need to introduce several layers of helper macros to make this work.

Comment: Aww, that's what I get for not trying it. aschelper was right anyway though; "%.*s" is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Not relevant to your example but important in similar situations if you a define like this:

```
#define SOMEONES_MIDDLE_NAME "Ray"
```

You can insert it into strings like this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "Billy " SOMEONES_MIDDLE_NAME " Cyrus", sizeof(buffer));
```

The compiler will automagically collect string literals into single blocks.